# CSS Filter Rotate bugg in ie7

Tags: css, filter, rotation, internet-explorer-7

So here's my problem:

I'm displaying an Iframe over an overlay-div. In this iframe a layout of circles with arrows drawn in between them is displayed (See image: http://i49.tinypic.com/oprb00.png). The arrows need to be rotated, this is done with css transform and the -filter solution för IE. The degree-value that the arrows should be rotated by is calculated dynamically and set with Jquery.

The problem I'm facing is a bug that only appears in ie7 (note that it doesn't appear in the ie7-compatibility-mode in ie9.).

The rotation itself works in ie7 but the problem is that around the rotated item a transparent box appears that allows you to see "through" the Iframe and it's containing div. This transparent box has the same dimensions (height, width) as the rotated div. If I remove the rotated items the transparency disappear.

The problem itself isn't how the rotate functionality is set, but why this "transparent" box appears, just wondering if this has happened to anyone else.

I've tried solving this by adding higher z-index properties to the elements related but with no success.

Picture of the occurance: http://i49.tinypic.com/oprb00.png

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to see the problem without you showing any code, but allow me to make an alternative suggestion:

There is a Javascript library called [CSS SandPaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/), which allows old IE versions to use the standard CSS `transform:rotate` style.

If you're having trouble with the IE-specific filter matrix (which is very tricky to work with), you could try using that to make your code simpler to work with and more similar across all browsers.

I know it's not a direct answer to the question, but I hope that helps.